# Openshift Bcrypt error

Tags: flask, openshift, bcrypt

I have a python app deployed on openshift. For some weird reason, I keep getting internal server error. I checked my logs to see that it said cannot find module named flask-Bcrypt. However, when I ssh into the app and do a pip freeze, I see flask-bcrypt installed.

Comment: Maybe "Bcrypt" vs "bcrypt"???

Comment: just change from capital `B` to small case `b`

Comment: Thanks guys, after spending time in my logs folder, I found out that I hadn't set secret key in the environment. I did that, and all is fixed now